# ¿Cuál es el origen de la terminación en -o para el pretérito de tercera persona singular?

Tags: etimología, verbos, historia, tiempos-verbales, conjugación

En las tres conjugaciones de verbos en español, la tercera persona singular forma su pretérito simple con terminación en *-o*, como «amó», «tuvo» o «dijo». Pero la forma de la que provienen en latín, a saber el perfecto, tenía terminación *-avit*, *-ait*, *-uit*, *-it*; en general *-it* final.

Cuando evolucionó hacia la forma española moderna, la forma para la primera persona singular que solo difería por la *-t* final de aquella de la tercera, resultó en una terminación con *-e* como «amé», «tuve» o «dije» y siguiendo el paradigma de otras palabras similares, la 3.p.s. debió haber resultado igual pues la pronta pérdida de la *-t* final habría dejado las formas de ambas personas iguales. Sin embargo hoy en día tenemos que este tiempo termina en *-o*, ¿por qué? ¿Qué origen tiene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some digging around on the internet reveals that Ian Mackenzie at the University of Newcastle (UK) knows the answer. The relevant page on verbs is [here](https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/i.e.mackenzie/hisverb.htm). In that page there are some links to other material which have not copied across in my version below. I know your question is in Spanish but I hope the English version below helps you.

> In contrast to what happened in the first person singular, the consonantal element -v- appears to have been retained in the third person singular, and the contraction consisted in the elision of the vowel ĭ that came immediately after it. The endings -āvĭt and -īvĭt were thus reduced to [-awt] and [-iwt] respectively.

> In the -āre ending, [aw] underwent its normal reduction to /o/, producing the ending -ot which is found in early Old Spanish. In the -īre ending, the semivowel [w] became syllabic, i.e. [ˈiwt] > [ˈiut]. As happened generally, /u/ in final syllables was replaced by /o/, resulting in the early Old Spanish ending -iot, initially pronounced [ˈiot] but over time evolving to [ˈjot]. The final /t/ of both -ot and -iot went the way of Latin final /t/ generally, not surviving much beyond the eleventh century. Following this latter development, the third person singular endings were as they are in modern Spanish, namely -ó and -ió (although the practice of indicating the stress with a written accent dates from the early modern period).